# Mysql: return all rows with distinct key, if same key then take one with highest timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table like below.

```
+---------+-----------+
|   key   |    ts     |
+---------+-----------+
|   key1  | 1200000000|
+---------+-----------+
|   key1  | 1300000000|
+---------+-----------+
|   key2  | 1200000000|
+---------+-----------+
```

I want to select *, such that I get all the distinct 'key's. For rows with same key, then I want the row with the highest ts. So in this example, I want to return:

```
+---------+-----------+
|   key1  | 1300000000|
+---------+-----------+
|   key2  | 1200000000|
+---------+-----------+
```

I think it's a combination of MAX and GROUP BY key, but could not figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?  This is a pretty basic aggregation (you have the correct keywords listed)...

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(ts) FROM table_name GROUP BY key);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said yourself, simply a matter of group by the `key` column, and max on the `ts` column

```
select key, max(ts) from yourTable group by key
```

Comment: Hmm okay, but this isn't a select * like asked in the question. For only those two columns it's indeed trivial.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple solution:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl t
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ts < t.ts AND key = t.key)
```

The alternative ist to group by key and get the max(ts) for each key in a sub select, then inner join with the original table on key and ts to get the rest of the columns.